# merge sort is in infinite loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to code a recursive merge sort. 
However, as I run the code I found out that the code does not go through the right array.
Please help me solve the problem.

```
void merge_sort_recursive(int *arr, int left, int right) {
    int mid;
    while (left < right) { 
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        merge_sort_recursive(arr, left, mid);
        merge_sort_recursive(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge_recursive(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void merge_recursive(int *arr, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int *buffer = new int[right + 1]; 
    int lPtr = left; 
    int rPtr = mid + 1;
    int bPtr = left; 

    while (lPtr <= mid && rPtr <= right) {
        if (arr[lPtr] < arr[rPtr]) 
            buffer[bPtr++] = arr[lPtr++];
        else
            buffer[bPtr++] = arr[rPtr++];
    }

    if (lPtr > mid) 
        for (int i = rPtr; i <= right; i++)
            buffer[bPtr++] = arr[i];
    else 
        for (int i = lPtr; i <= mid; i++)
            buffer[bPtr++] = arr[i];

    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) 
        arr[i] = buffer[i]; 
}
```

Comment: change `while (left < right)` to `if (left < right)` and your code will run perfectly.

Comment: Note that you're leaking memory. I see a `new[]` but no matching `delete[]`

Comment: Side note: debuggers are great at helping understand an infinite loop. Run the program in the debugger. Wait for the program to enter the infinite loop. Step through the loop a few times and watch what the program is doing. Pay special attention to the variables related to the exit conditions.

Comment: @ReginaKang: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in function `merge_sort_recursive`, you should not loop `while (left < right)` but just proceed recursively `if (left < right)`.
- you should remove the output in `merge_sort_recursive`. I suppose you only have it there for debugging purposes.
- in function `merge_recursive` you allocate a temporary array of size `right + 1`. This is much too large, `right - left + 1` is sufficient (with adjustments on the index values).
- you do not `delete` the temporary array, causing substantial memory leaks,
- the test in the first merge loop should use `<=` instead of `<`,

The main problem is the `while` loop that prevents returning from the recursive calls.

Here is a modified version:

```c
void merge_sort_recursive(int *arr, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) { 
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        merge_sort_recursive(arr, left, mid);
        merge_sort_recursive(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge_recursive(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}

void merge_recursive(int *arr, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int *buffer = new int[right - left + 1];
    int lPtr = left;
    int rPtr = mid + 1;
    int bPtr = 0;

    while (lPtr <= mid && rPtr <= right) {
        if (arr[lPtr] <= arr[rPtr]) 
            buffer[bPtr++] = arr[lPtr++];
        else
            buffer[bPtr++] = arr[rPtr++];
    }
    /* copy the remaining elements from the left part */
    while (lPtr <= mid) {
        buffer[bPtr++] = arr[lPtr++];
    }
    /* no need to copy the remaining elements from the right part 
       because they already are at the final position */
    for (int i = 0; i < bPtr; i++) {
        arr[left + i] = buffer[i];
    }
    delete[] buffer;
}
```